# WFLYNAM0027 : ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory

Tags: jboss, ejb, ejb-3.0, wildfly

Enviornment- wildfly-9.0.2.Final, EJB 3.0

Following error occurred while trying to connect Test.java class(deployed as module at wildfly-9.0.2.Final@machine-A) to EJB whilch is deployed on jboss at machine-B(291.861.301.732).

```
17:02:46,666 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0027: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.test.ear.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory from [Module "deployment.test.ear.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader]]
17:02:46,667 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:118)
17:02:46,667 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:99)
17:02:46,670 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154)
17:02:46,670 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:89)
17:02:46,670 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:43)
17:02:46,687 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory from [Module "deployment.test.ear.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
17:02:46,688 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
17:02:46,688 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
17:02:46,688 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
17:02:46,688 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
17:02:46,688 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
```

Test.java class is present in testclient.jar & testclient.jar has been deplyed as a module using command

```
module add --name=testclient --resources=/Downloads/lib/test/client/testclient.jar --dependencies=javax.api
```

Test.java class

```
package com.testmodule.pojo;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class Test { 
public void getDbConnection(){
    try{
        Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
        jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote://291.861.301.732:4447");
        jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "testuser");
        jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "testpassword");
        jndiProps.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}}
```

why this error has been occurred, For visiblity of 'org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory' to testclient.jar, should i have to **add more dependencies(currently only javax.api)** while deploying testclient.jar as a module? or any other issue which is causing error? Class 'org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory' is also present in $WILDFLY_HOME/bin/client/jboss-client.jar

Note - 291.861.301.732 is the remote system ip, on which ejb is deployed at jboss. ,This ejb is invoking from Test.java(remote client) using JNDI.

There is no jnp in wildfly-9.0.2.Final(which was in JBOSS 5.x), so i replaced property "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory" to value org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory". why still error is occurred?

**Following has been added after receving comment 'Try putting jboss-client.jar in the runtime path, as part of WEB-INF/lib maybe' by 'Sampada Wagde'**

I am not able to understand, In this scenarion test.jsp (present in test.ear-->test.war-->test.jsp) file is calling function getDbConnection of Test.java file. Test.java file is present in testclient.jar and this testclient.jar has been deployed as a module.
As per your suggestion, when i put 'jboss-client.jar' in test.ear-->test.war-->WEB-INF-->lib, problem was solved, now while accessing
application 'org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory' ClassNotFound exception was not occurred...**But my problem is that there are multiple war's files(Eg..test.war,test1.war,test2.war) and each war file is accessing Test.java file(present in testclient.jar), so i have to put 'jboss-client.jar' file in WEB-INF/lib of each war archive. which will be very complex for me, is there any other approach available?** and secondly how this problem is solved by putting 'jboss-client.jar' into WEB-INF/lib direcory as 'org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory' is present in testclient.jar(Not in test.ear-->test.war).

**Following has been added after receving reply 'jboss-client.jar is required by the server at runtime...' by 'Sampada Wagde'**

I also tried following steps
1. By putting 'jboss-deployment-structure.xml' in test.ear-->META-INF-->jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="testclient" export="true" />
        <module name="jboss-client" export="true" />
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
```

2. Deploying  module name as

   ```
   module add --name=jboss-client --resources=/Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/bin/client/jboss-client.jar
   ```

but still the following error occurred.

```
14:14:34,376 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (default task-1) Failed to define class org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory in Module "jboss-client:main" from local module loader @707f7052 (finder: local module finder @11028347 (roots: /Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules,/Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules/system/layers/base)): java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/jboss/naming/remote/client/InitialContextFactory (Module "jboss-client:main" from local module loader @707f7052 (finder: local module finder @11028347 (roots: /Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules,/Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules/system/layers/base)))
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:437)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:269)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:77)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:560)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/naming/spi/InitialContextFactory
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:353)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:432)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory from [Module "jboss-client:main" from local module loader @707f7052 (finder: local module finder @11028347 (roots: /Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules,/Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules/system/layers/base))]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
14:14:34,391 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /test/test.jsp: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/jboss/naming/remote/client/InitialContextFactory (Module "jboss-client:main" from local module loader @707f7052 (finder: local module finder @11028347 (roots: /Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules,/Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules/system/layers/base)))
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:848)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:777)
at org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:85)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/jboss/naming/remote/client/InitialContextFactory (Module "jboss-client:main" from local module loader @707f7052 (finder: local module finder @11028347 (roots: /Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules,/Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules/system/layers/base)))
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:437)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:269)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:77)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:560)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/naming/spi/InitialContextFactory
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:353)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:432)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory from [Module "jboss-client:main" from local module loader @707f7052 (finder: local module finder @11028347 (roots: /Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules,/Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/modules/system/layers/base))]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
```

Comment: Try putting jboss-client.jar in the runtime path, as part of WEB-INF/lib maybe

Comment: @Sampada Wagde...Thankx for reply...Kindly see edited section.

Comment: Is it possible to clean a little your question in order to have only the relevant parts of your problem? Since it has really big formatting/spelling problems, is quite hard to help you. Also, are you using some kind of building tool, such as Maven?

Comment: @aribeiro... kindly see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468767/classnotfoundexception-org-jboss-naming-remote-client-initialcontextfactory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your own module depend on a module that contains not only the jboss-client jar, but also all the dependencies of jboss-client, this might just be other modules or possibly other jars too. The first class it's moaning about being missing is javax/naming/spi/InitialContextFactory so edit the module.xml for the jboss-client module to depend on javax.api

Answer (score 2):

jboss-client.jar is required by the server at runtime. There are several ways of providing jars to a JBoss server -

1. include jars in MANIFEST.MF (this is generally used for your own application jars)
2. include jars in WEB-INF/lib - if the jar is specific to the given web project or WAR
3. include jars in a module class loader and provide it to the web project via jboss-deploymet-structure.xml . This is done when there are multiple WARS and some of them (not all) need the jars.
4. include jars in a module class loader and provide it to the server via global modules in standalone.xml . This is done when the jars are being referenced by all applications deployed on the server.

For details on modules in JBoss, please refer to this link -
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7

As to your question on how putting the jboss-client.jar in a WAR instead of testclient.jar is resolving the issue, the answer is the same - this is how class loading works.

Comment: .....THANKX FOR REPLY...I added the module with command --
module add --name=jboss-client --resources=~/Downloads/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/bin/client/jboss-client.jar
and than create module testclient as with dependency ->jboss-client --
module add --name=testclient --resources=~/Downloads/lib/test/client/testclient.jar --dependencies=javax.api,jboss-client ----
but still the same error occurred....kindly see where i am doing wrong.

Comment: "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/naming/spi/InitialContextFactory" - this is what is causing problem for you now. Consider adding sun.jdk as a dependency in your module.xml

Comment: Is i am on correct path...? ...And how this(sun.jdk) dependncy will be added?

Comment: thankx for reply sir,module.xml is automatically generated by jboss-cli.sh,so I also tried this by command "module add --name=testclient --resources=~/Downloads/lib/test/client/testclient.jar --dependencies=javax.api,sun.jdk" ...but its not working.