# REST Web Services - Swagger getting error 404

Tags: java, rest, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using swagger definition for my Web Services, I already created the java (JAX-RS) project. When I deploy the project into the server (JBoss 7.1.1) I get some errors but the project gets deployed successfully, but when i go and try an operation it always return the error 404.
[image: Example of a request]

I haven't done anything in the impl dir but for all requests it should return the default response, which is "magic!"

```
return Response.ok().entity(new ApiResponseMessage(ApiResponseMessage.OK, "magic!")).build();
```

The errors are:

```
22:53:16,318 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web]. [default-host].[/VoiceAuthMiddleware]] (MSC service thread 1-6) Marking servlet jersey as unavailable
22:53:16,319 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/VoiceAuthMiddleware]] (MSC service thread 1-6) Servlet /VoiceAuthMiddleware threw load() exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer from [Module "deployment.VoiceAuthMiddlewareEAR.ear.VoiceAuthMiddleware.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1156) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]

22:53:16,325 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/VoiceAuthMiddleware]] (MSC service thread 1-6) Marking servlet DefaultJaxrsConfig as unavailable
22:53:16,325 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/VoiceAuthMiddleware]] (MSC service thread 1-6) Servlet /VoiceAuthMiddleware threw load() exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig from [Module "deployment.VoiceAuthMiddlewareEAR.ear.VoiceAuthMiddleware.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1156) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
```

***Dependencies:***

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs-server</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>swagger-jaxrs-server</name>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty-version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <webApp>
            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
          </webApp>
          <webAppSourceDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</webAppSourceDirectory>
          <stopPort>8079</stopPort>
          <stopKey>stopit</stopKey>
          <httpConnector>
            <port>8080</port>
            <idleTimeout>60000</idleTimeout>
          </httpConnector>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
              <daemon>true</daemon>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>src/gen/java</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-jersey-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>${swagger-core-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.8.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <properties>
    <swagger-core-version>1.5.7</swagger-core-version>
    <jetty-version>9.2.9.v20150224</jetty-version>
    <jersey-version>1.18.1</jersey-version>
    <slf4j-version>1.6.3</slf4j-version>
    <junit-version>4.8.1</junit-version>
    <servlet-api-version>2.5</servlet-api-version>
  </properties>
</project>
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: This seems relevant with your case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658048/getting-a-classnotfoundexception-using-eclipse-jboss-7-1-1-and-jersey-1

Comment: you maybe missing a jar dependency possibly a jersey library judging by the missing class `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer` . similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911293/jersey-rest-application-using-servlet-wrapping-does-not-deploy-on-jboss-as

Comment: it's odd i'm using maven :/

Comment: Can you share your dependencies?  This class should live in the swagger-jaxrs library.

Comment: Dependencies shared.