# Jboss EAP 7.0.0 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

I am migrating a service from Jboss 5.1 to Jboss EAP 7.0.0.
It is successfully build in jdk 1.8 using maven 3.9.9 and successfully deployed in jboss EAP 7.0.0.

During deployment it is showing `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. This service contains only local ejb no remote ejbs.

**EJb lookup class -**

```
        String contextFactory = SysConfigUtil.getJndiFactory();
        String ejbLocalJndi = SysConfigUtil.getTimerEjbLocalJndi();
        Properties environment = new Properties();
        environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, contextFactory);
        Context ctx;
        environment.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        environment.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", new Boolean(true));
        ctx = new InitialContext(environment);
        logger.info("************ before lookup");
        ejb = (ISystemConfigurationTimerLocal) ctx.lookup(ejbLocalJndi);
        logger.info("************ after lookup");
```

**Stack Trace -**

```
javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0027: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader f
or Module "deployment.SystemConfiguration.ear.system-configuration-lifecycle.sar:main" from Service Module Loader [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jb
oss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory from [Module "deployment.SystemConfiguration.ear.system-configuration-lifecycle.sar:main" from Service Module Loader]]
    org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:118)
    org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:99)
    javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154)
    org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:89)
    org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:43)
    javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    com.abcd.services.core.systemconfiguration.conn.impl.SystemConfigurationTimerEjbExecutor.getSystemConfigurationTimerEJB(SystemConfigurationTimerEjbExecutor.java:96)
    com.abcd.services.core.systemconfiguration.conn.impl.SystemConfigurationTimerEjbExecutor.startScheduler(SystemConfigurationTimerEjbExecutor.java:56)
    com.abcd.services.core.systemconfiguration.conn.impl.SystemConfigurationAppLifeCycle.start(SystemConfigurationAppLifeCycle.java:65)
    org.jboss.as.service.AbstractService.invokeLifecycleMethod(AbstractService.java:76)
    org.jboss.as.service.StartStopService$1.run(StartStopService.java:61)
    java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory from [Module "deployment.SystemConfiguration.ear.system-configuration-lifec
ycle.sar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:113)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441217/wflynam0027-classnotfoundexception-org-jboss-naming-remote-client-initialcont

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have never needed to provide environment properties to `new InitialContext()` when looking up local objects in any version of JBossAS or WildFly.

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
ejb = (ISystemConfigurationTimerLocal) ctx.lookup(ejbLocalJndi);
```

should be all that you need.

FWIW, the property configuration that you provided is for remote standalone clients, and is incorrect even for server -> server calls.

Comment: Thanks by removing environment properties from new InitialContext() my issue resolved.